# HAXM is not working

Tags: android

I created a AVD with 512 MB RAM, then I got a warning:

*- Increasing RAM Size to 1 GB*

I get a message in the console:

*HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode.*

[image]

Any ideas what the cause can be?